# Python convert 32 bit to 16 bit tiff

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff

Is there a simple way to convert a 32-bit .tif to 16-bit .tif?  In IDL, write_tiff allows /short instead of /float.  Does Python do that?  Instead, I have tried this:

```
i32 = Image.open('image.tif')
<Image.Image image mode=F size=2016x2016 at 0x102A3E998>
i32.convert('L').save('newimage.tif')
```

ImageJ (viewer) opens the tif and says that this image is 8-bit, not 16-bit.

Comment: Do you need the output to be tiff? Is the desired output to be used for viewing or for numerical calculation? If you want to view only, you can try `a = numpy.asarray(i32); matplotlib.pyplot.imshow(a)`.

Answer (score 3):

From [PIL documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm): The `'L'` mode is for 8-bit greyscale images, and your original image is a 32-bit float (mode `'F'`), not integer! To get 16 bit integer images, you can try to use `'I;16'` for the mode; this is at least supported in my Pillow 2.0.0 (Ubuntu 14.04):

```
f32 = Image.open('image.tif')
f32.convert('I;16').save('newimage.tif')
```

Comment: I tried this, but when I convert to 'I;16' the .histogram changes from a ~Gaussian centered around 95/255 for the 32-bit image to delta function at 255 for the 16-bit image (i.e., just white).  Anyway to correct that?

Comment: It is certainly a bit hard to debug since I currently don't have your file, nor do I have any software supporting either f32 or i16 tiffs :D

Answer (score 1):

The Python Imaging Library doesn't support 16-bit pixel depth. See "modes" in the [concepts section](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/concepts.htm) of the Handbook.

The [same goes](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/handbook/concepts.html) for the derivative library Pillow.

Try e.g. [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/index.php) (which has python [bindings](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/api.php)) with the `-depth` option.